# Why is it possible to specify React elements (JavaScript objects) as children to a React component?

Tags: reactjs

The result of a call to `React.createElement(...)` is an object along the lines of:

```
{
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
    key: null,
    props: {children: Array(2)},
    ref: null,
    type: "div",
    _owner: null,
    _store: {validated: true},
    _self: null,
    _source: null,
    __proto__: Object
}
```

I take this to be the representation of a DOM element in React's virtual DOM (please let me know if this is not correct).

Whilst creating functionality for dynamically adding elements to a page, I mistakingly tried by keeping an array of react elements in the state object:

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { things: [], count: 0 }
  }
  updateForm(obj, cb) {...} 
  render() {
    return (<>
        {this.props.render({
          updateForm: this.updateForm.bind(this),
          ...this.state
        })}
    </>)
  }
}

const makeThing = props =>
  <div>
    I am a thing. count is: {props.count}
  </div>

const App = () =>
  <Form 
  render={
    props => (
      <div>
        {props.things.map(t => t)} // RENDERING ELEMENTS DIRECTLY
        <button onClick={() => props.updateForm({things: [...props.things, makeThing(props)]})}>Add thing</button>
        <button onClick={() => props.updateForm({count: props.count + 1})}>Increase count</button>
      </div>
    )
  } />
```

I have subsequently learned that specifying pre-created react elements as children of some component just isn't a good idea.

Why is it even possible? Surely there is NEVER a case when I would actually want to do this... I.e. it should error?

Comment: Why should it error? I'm not sure I understand the question--I don't understand why it's in state since you never use the things in the state, the only thing that's happening here is you're creating an array of the objects (via `map`) which are then rendered. This is pretty much how dynamic objects are created and rendered, e.g., columns and cells in a BlueprintJS `<Table>` are often created this way. Can you be more specific about your concern(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any problem with what you've posted. You're free to create your Components wherever and however you like and pass them around. They're just objects so they can go in state if you like.

The only caveat is that it's more efficient (and better in terms of separation of concerns) to pass around your viewData and handlers and then use that to render your components at the point when you actually need to.

Comment: Nothing wrong per say.. i.e. adding things to the DOM. but it's in a distinctly un-react way. if it is done... then it's probably by mistake

Comment: @ZachSmith How is this a "distinctly un-React way"? Keeping component references is *very* React, for example, a map of states to components, a collection of data rows, etc. This happens all the time in React.

Comment: In this case the map function is adding pre-rendered elements as children. So they are never re-rendered, meaning that they don't update when "count" is changed

Comment: @ZachSmith It's not that they're "pre-rendered", they're not rendered until they're executed--it's that their `props` aren't what you think they should be. React doesn't know your *intent*, just your *code*. There's no way for React to know what you *meant* to do, hence there's zero reason this should be an error--it's not React's fault you're passing in the wrong props.

Comment: What do you mean by executed in this case? They are an object - so they can't be executed per say...